# How to put a conditon on 2D vector i,j

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, operators, 2d-vector

I was trying to write a BFS code, I fail to understand anything about this error. Why can't I simply use
visited[i][j]==1 ?

```
int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) 
{
    int n = grid.size();
    int m = grid[0].size();
    vector<vector<int>> vis
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        vector<int>v;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            v.push_back(0);
        }
        vis.push_back(v);
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if ((vis[i][j] == 0) && (grid[i][j] == '1'))
            {
                bfs(grid, vis, i, j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

};
```

Char 22: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >, std::vector >::value_type' {aka 'std::vector'} and 'int')
         if((vis[i][j]==0)&&(grid[i][j]=='1'))

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> vis` is missing a semicolon and the brackets in this function do not line up. If these are typos transcribing the code into the question, please fix them. If they are errors in the source code, please fix them and see if you still have a question.

Comment: I read your comment and you are right I misread the code originally, I edited my post let me know if its of any help

Comment: Still buggy. Please check again  . . .

Answer (score 0):

Like @user4581301 said in comment, your main issue here is syntax-related.

Line `vector<vector<int>> vis` needs a trailing semicolon: `vector<vector<int>> vis;` and your last line, `};`, shouldn't exist, at least without the context of a surrounding `class` definition or similar.

**This compiles:***

```
int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
    int n = grid.size();
    int m = grid[0].size();
    vector<vector<int>> vis;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vector<int> v;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            v.push_back(0);
        }
        vis.push_back(v);
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if((vis[i][j] == 0) && (grid[i][j] == '1')) {
                bfs(grid, vis, i, j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

*We don't know your definition for the `bfs(std::vector<std::vector<char>>&, std::vector<std::vector<int>>, int, int)` function. You're also missing the `using namespace std` that would be required to make this syntax viable. Without them, this code snippet **doesn't** compile.*